# Erro. UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: node.js

No browser, o código a seguir funciona normalmente:

```
const get = async () => {
  return Promise.reject('Oops!')
}

get()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch((err) => { throw new Error(err) })
```

Mas no Node.js (versão `8.10.0`), ao executar o mesmo código, eu recebo o erro:

> ```
> (node:2508) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Oops!
>     at get.then.catch.err (C:\Users\fraza\Desktop\NodeTests\extra.test.js:5:46)
>     at <anonymous>
>     at runMicrotasksCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:121:5)
>     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
>     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
>     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
>     at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
> (node:2508) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
> (node:2508) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
> ```

O que é isso? Por que acontece? Isso é prejudicial? Como resolver?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O evento [unhandledRejection](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection) é emitido sempre que um Promise é rejeitado e nenhum manipulador de erro é anexado à promessa.

Para resolver, basta apenas tratar a rejeição:

```
return Promise.reject('Oops!').catch(err => {
  throw new Error(err);
});
```

O código completo:

```
const get = async () => {
  return Promise.reject('Oops!').catch(err => {
    throw new Error(err);
  });
};

get()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
```

> Veja funcionando no console do navegador em [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-xf9yqo) e em um terminal em [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/LoneFearlessMemorypool)

Answer (score -3):

No meu caso foi a versão errada do node no terminal. Tinha fechado o projeto para recarregar uma extensão e esqueci do nvm use. Simples.