# erro em requisção post utilizando axios do lado do servidor

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

Boa tarde, estou criando uma função em um api que irá fazer uma requisição via post, fiz utilizando fetch na pagina com reactjs e agora tenho que migrar para a api porém ao fazer a requisição ela gera um erro dizendo que o fetch não é uma função, ao migrar pro axios e gerou o seguinte erro:

> (node:3612) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 400

sei que esse erro se dá ao fato do serviço estar fora do ar porém ele estava funcionando com as requisições fecth feita na pagina.

```
const dataCard = req.body;
let axiosConfig = {
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        MerchantId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        MerchantKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    }
}
const url  = "https://apisandbox.braspag.com.br/v2/sales/"
const data = JSON.stringify(dataCard)


await axios.post(url,data,axiosConfig)
 .then((res)=>{
     console.log(res)
 })
```

Comment: Meu erro foi do lado do servidor e não do lado do cliente, as perguntas são diferentes.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi meu problema desta maneira:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");


fetch("https://apisandbox.braspag.com.br/v2/sales/", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        MerchantId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        MerchantKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(dataCard),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro [`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/285695/erro-unhandledpromiserejectionwarning) é invocado pelo Node.js sempre que uma [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) é rejeitada e não recebe a devida tratativa.

---

> *[...]* sei que esse erro se dá ao fato do **serviço estar fora do ar** *[...]*

O fato do serviço estar fora do ar faz com que o Axios não consiga finalizar a requisição e, por isso, um erro será lançado. Como a biblioteca em questão trabalha com `Promise`s e você não realizou a devida tratativa, o erro sempre será lançado quando algum problema acontecer durante a requisição.

Para tratar o erro diretamente na cadeira da promessa, você pode encadear um [`catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch). Algo assim:

```js
axios.post(url, data, config)
  .then((res) => {
    // Faça aqui o que quiser com a resposta da requisição.
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Trate o erro aqui.
    console.log('Whoops! Houve um erro.', error.message || error)
  })
```

Se você estiver usando `async`/`await`, pode usar o `try`/`catch`:

```js
try {
  const response = await axios.post(url, data, config)
  // Faça aqui o que quiser com a resposta da requisição.
} catch (error) {
  // Trate o erro aqui.
  console.log('Whoops! Houve um erro.', error.message || error)
}
```

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?