# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error

Tags: mysql, node.js, express.js

estou com este erro e não consegui achar nenhuma pergunta no StackOverflow que me ajudasse...
o erro está sendo gerado provavelmento por causa de uma **promisse**

**Index.js**

```
const path = require('path')
const app = express()
const port =  process.env.PORT || 3000
const mysql = require('mysql')

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'HOST',
    user: 'USER',
    pass: 'PASS',
    database: 'BD' 
})
const dependencies = {
  connection
}

const users = require('./routes/users')

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('home'))
app.use('/usuarios', users(dependencies))

//view engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

connection.connect(() => {
  app.listen(port, () => console.log('Servidor no ar, porta:', +port))    
})
```

**Routes/users.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const usersController = require('../controllers/users')

const usersRouter = ({ connection }) => {
    const router = express.Router()     

    router.get('/', usersController.index.bind(null, connection))

    return router

}

module.exports = usersRouter
```

**Controllers/users.js**

```
const users = require('../models/users')

const index = async(connection, req, res) => {
    const results = await users.findAll(connection)
    res.render('olá')
}

module.exports = {
    index
}
```

**Models/users.js**

```
const findAll = (connection) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query('select * from users', (err, results) => {
            if(err){
                reject(err)
            }else{
                resolve(results)
            }
        })
    })
}


module.exports = {
    findAll
}
```

Alguma alma caridosa pra me socorrer?! kkkkk

Comment: console.log(connection) no método findAll retorna o que?

Comment: o node não chega até o fim do método... 
subi o console.log 1 nível e mostrou isso no item _fatalError: { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mysql.umbler.com:41890 mysql.umbler.com:41890:3306
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete]

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/285695/erro-unhandledpromiserejectionwarning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente você não conectou-se ao banco de dados antes de executar a query.

```
connection.connect((err) => {
  if(err){
    console.log('não conectado ao mysql', err)
  }else{
    app.listen(port, () => console.log('Servidor no ar, porta:', port))    
  }
})
```

Importante verificar também se os seus dados de conexão estão corretos.