# Unhandled promise rejection typescript e node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, react, async

Boa a noite a todos!
estou desenvolvendo um app com react, node e typescript e estava programando uma rota com método post para inserção de dados usando banco de dados sqlite e testando no insomnia mas ao executar o arquivo ele me retorna um erro de Unhandled promise rejection e não sei tratar esse evento.

essa e a minha rota:

```
routes.post('/points', async(request, response)=>{

    const {
        name,
        email,
        whatsapp,
        latitude,
        longitude,
        city,
        uf,
        items
    }=request.body;


   await knex('points').insert({
        image: 'image_fake',
        name,
        email,
        whatsapp,
        latitude,
        longitude,
        city,
        uf,

    })
    return response.json({sucess: true});

});
```

no insomnia eu faço uma requisiçao do tipo post e o corpo em json da seguinte forma

```
{
    "name": "Mercado Livre",
    "email": "contato@mercado.com",
    "whatsapp": "3198774664",
    "latitude": "-45.4892729",
    "longitude": "-35.4324233",
    "city": "BH",
    "uf": "MG",
    "items": [
        1,
        2,
        6
    ]
}
```

o esperado era que eu tivesse um "sucess: true;" como resposta de acordo com meu return response.json({sucess: true});

porem ele me retorna o seguinte:

(node:13488) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: insert into `points` (`city`, `email`, `image`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `name`, `uf`, `whatsapp`) values ('BH', 'contato@mercado.com', 'image_fake', '-45.4892729', '-35.4324233', 'Mercado Livre', 'MG', '3198774664') - SQLITE_ERROR: table points has no column named whatsapp
    (node:13488) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
    (node:13488) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

será que alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

O Express não possui um método para capturar rejeições de promessas nativamente. Portanto, como você está utilizando `async`/`await`, deve sempre garantir que nenhuma promessa rejeitada "saia" de dentro do roteador, já que não há outro mecanismo para tratá-la.

Você pode usar blocos `try`/`catch`:

```js
routes.post('/points', async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const {
      name,
      email,
      // ...
    } = request.body;

    await knex('points').insert({
      name,
      email,
      // ...
    });

    return response.json({ sucess: true });
  } catch (error) {
    response.json({
      error: true,
      message: error.message
    }); 
  }
});
```

No seu caso específico, o erro está na tentativa de inserir um nojo registro em `points`. De acordo com a mensagem de erro, não há coluna `whatsapp` na tabela:

> ```
> SQLITE_ERROR: table points has no column named whatsapp
> ```

Há outras maneiras de se resolver esse problema, como usar alguma função de ordem superior (*higher order function*), que fará um tratamento de erros mais genérico, ou encadear o [`catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) diretamente no método que retorna a `Promise`.

Para saber mais sobre o aviso `unhandledPromiseRejection`, leia [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/285695/erro-unhandledpromiserejectionwarning).

---

Também coloquei ponto e vírgula no final de uma linha que faltava. Pode parecer "frescura", mas isso evita [algumas situações bizarras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/432960) que podem ocorrer se você não os usar (veja mais sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3341)).

Comment: o try catch ajudou bastante a identificar o erro e com isso pude perceber que havia criado o nome da variavel whatsapp errado na tabela e com isso dava erro na inserção.