# Verificação de promessa flutuante em TypeScript ESLint (no floating promises)

Tags: javascript, typescript, promises, eslint

Eu tenho o seguinte método:

```
async sync({model, event, data}: {model: string, event: string, data: Category}) {
  if (model === 'category') {
    switch (event) {
      case 'created':
        await this.categoryRepo.create({
          ...data,
          createdAt: new Date(),
          updatedAt: new Date()
        });
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Mas quando faço a chamada dele:

```
this.sync({model, event, data});
```

O TypeScript me retorna o seguinte erro no `this`:

> ESLint: Promises must be handled appropriately or explicitly marked as
> ignored with the `void`
> operator.(@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises)

Como posso tratar isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lembre-se que toda [função assíncrona](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas) em JavaScript retorna (sempre) uma [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Desse modo, é ideal que você trate-a devidamente (já que se resolverá em um outro momento de execução do código), seja com `then` ou `catch`.

O *erro*, de acordo com a [documentação da regra em questão](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-floating-promises.md), dá-se porque:

> Promessas não tratadas podem causar uma série de problemas, como sequência imprópria de operações, rejeições ignoradas etc.

A mesma documentação ainda indica que para *corrigir* o *erro* pode-se utilizar o método [`Promise.prototype.catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) ou o segundo argumento de [`Promise.prototype.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) (cujo efeito é similar ao do referido `catch`).

Então, no seu caso, precisa fazer algo como:

```
this.sync({ model, event, data }).catch((error) => {
  // Lide com o erro...
});
```

Ou ainda:

```
this.sync({ model, event, data }).then(
  () => {
    // Tudo correu bem (1º argumento do then).
  },
  (error) => {
    // Lide com o erro (2º argumento do then).
  }
);
```

É mais uma garantia para prevenir futuros erros. É um exemplo de  "boa prática". Claro que é bom fazer, mas é bom também entender **porquê** é bom fazê-lo.

Relacionado em ambiente Node.js é o [UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/285695/69296) (aviso de rejeição de promessa não tratada).

---

Apenas uma observação final: não é um erro do TypeScript em si, mas sim do *ESLint plugin TypeScript*. Você pode identificar a origem do erro ao final da mensagem de erro:

> ESLint: Promises must be handled appropriately or explicitly marked as ignored with the void operator. **(@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises)**

Note ao final que a mensagem de erro provém da regra [`no-floating-promises`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-floating-promises.md) do *plugin* `@typescript-eslint` do ESLint.

Um erro do TypeScript seria algo como:

> Parameter 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type. **ts(7006)**

Note que esse erro hipotético é, de fato, do TypeScript. Mais especificamente, o erro com código (interno do TypeScript) 7006.